# Simplifying a 'fractal-like' expression with tetration

Tags: closed-form, tetration, big-numbers, power-towers, hyperoperation

Let $f_2(n)=2^n n$ and let $f_3$ be defined recursively as
$$
f_3(n)=\underbrace{f_2\cdots f_2}_{n\text{ times}}(n)=f_2^n(n).
$$
This will lead to tetration, but is it possible to write $f_3$ in a closed formula, using the notation ${^{n}a}$ for tetration (or even Knuth's up-arrow notation)?

I tried to write a simple code to see an emerging pattern, but simplifications seem somehow tricky. Also, ${^{n}2}$ seems to be relatively simple to recognise in the expansion of $f_3$, but the remaining terms are somewhat complicated and it almost feels like the expression behaves like a fractal. Any ideas?

Here are the first four iterations, might help to picture the pattern.
\begin{align*}
f_2(n)&=2^n n\\
f_2^2(n)&=2^{(2^n+1)n}n=2^{2^nn}2^nn\\
f_2^3(n)&=2^{(2^{(2^{n}+1)n}+2^n+1)n}n=2^{2^{2^nn}2^nn}2^{2^nn}2^nn\\
f_2^4(n)&=2^{(2^{(2^{(2^n+1)n}+2^n+1)n}+2^{(2^n+1)n}+2^n+1)n}n
\end{align*}
Just to give some context, these functions were defined and discussed in a recent [Numberphile video about $\text{TREE}(n)$ and Graham's number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0X9DYRLmTNY) (see around minute $10$).

Comment: Look at this page : https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/ which is a superb survey over the world of large numbers.

Comment: @Peter Looks very interesting, I'll take a look!

Comment: @Peter I noticed you've already seen my other question on nested tetration. The original motivation comes from this question (see draft answer below). I'm thankful for your help.

Comment: TREE(3) is already a completely other league compared to the much,much,much,much smaller Graham-number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no, because there's a mix of operations being iterated: either multiplication and exponentiation, or if you bring the multiplication up a level, addition and exponentiation.

As far as approximations go though, you can see [here](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/User_blog:Simply_Beautiful_Art/Even_tighter_bounds_on_f_3_in_the_fast_growing_hierarchy) for some tight bounds:

$$n\operatorname{Tet}(2^n,1,n)\le f_3(n)\le\operatorname{Tet}(2\sqrt[n]n,n,n)$$

where $\operatorname{Tet}(a,b,c)=\underbrace{a~\widehat~~a~\widehat~~\dots~\widehat~~a~\widehat~~}_cb$ is $c$ powers of $a$ with $b$ on top.

Comment: For some reason the LaTeX isn't compiling on the link you gave.

Comment: The site no longer supports MathJax as it used to. You can copy the text over there onto here and it will render if you wish to see the proof of the above inequalities.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expand a bit more on why the mix of operations makes it impossible to simplify (check my answer below)? I understand the difficulty, but not the impossibility of it.

Comment: @samwolfe Tetration and the like simply do not involve iterating mixed combinations of operations, and one can clearly see this grows about as fast as tetration, and nothing other than tetration unless you clarify grows that fast.

Comment: The fact that I'm trying to use tetration to express an iterative expression in closed form does not justify that I can't do it. All I need to simplify are nested tetrations, and that is potentially impossible (why?). I'm afraid, however, that your answer does not answer my question, but I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Tetration is by definition repeated exponentiation. Since this is clearly not repeated exponentiation, you can't express it in terms of tetration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101294/discussion-between-sam-wolfe-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a potential solution. $f_3$ may be expressed as
$$
f_3(n)=\log_2\left(g^{n}\left(2^n \right) \right),
$$
where $g(n)={}^2n$. Indeed, iterating over $g$, which corresponds to the iterations of $f_2$, we have
\begin{align}
f_2(n)&=\log_2\left(g\left(2^n \right) \right)=\log_2\left(2^{2^nn} \right)=2^nn\\
f_2^2(n)&=\log_2\left(g^2\left(2^n \right)\right)=\log_2\left({}^2(2^{2^nn} )\right)=\log_2\left(2^{2^{2^nn}2^nn} \right)=2^{2^nn}2^nn\\
f_2^3(n)&=\log_2\left(g^3\left(2^n \right)\right)=\log_2\left({}^2({}^2(2^{2^nn} ))\right)=\log_2\left(2^{2^{2^{2^nn}2^nn}2^{2^nn}2^nn} \right)=2^{2^{2^nn}2^nn}2^{2^nn}2^nn\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
It is then clear that the only simplification remaining is of the following
$$
g^n(a)={}^{\overbrace{2\,\cdots\, 2}^{n\text{ times}}}a.
$$
While in general it is not true that ${}^a({}^bn)={}^{ab}n$, a closed formula for $g^n(a)$ might be possible. Any comments are appreciated. A follow-up question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418870/nested-tetration-properties).

**Note:** Even though this is not a full solution, I decided to post it as an answer in order to present my ideas more clearly.

**Edit note:** Based on a comment by @r.e.s., I simplified a bit my original expression for $f_3$ by noticing that $g(2^n)=2^{2^nn}$.

Comment: Note that $g(2^n)=2^{2^nn},$ so we can also write $f_3(n)=\log_2\left(g^n\left(2^n \right) \right).$

Comment: @r.e.s. Good point, thank you. I will edit my answer based on your comment.